# Convert Decimal to Date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting an output like `15.73` as decimal and I want it to be converted to a time format. `15.73` is basically something like `15:43`. How can I achieve this result? Below is my query:

```sql
SELECT ((TRUNC(lt.date_start + 1) - 1/(24*60*60)) - lt.date_start)*24 DUR, lt.date_start 
from losttime lt
where lt.date_start >= to_date('02/07/2020 08:00' , 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI')
```

and *currently the output is coming in decimals* as attached.

[image: table showing the query output]

Comment: the column you are calculating is kind of an elapsed_time , right ? you want this format hh:mi without seconds ?

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez correct

Comment: Does `DUR` represent a number of days, or hours, or minutes, or seconds? Basically, if `DUR` = 1, what does that mean? Also - in future, please do not post images of code or data; instead, post what you've got as text, which can then be copied and pasted. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica if DUR=1 then it means 1 hour. Regarding the output image i tried many times to copy the text output but always fail when formatting it. But the code i posted is text.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica looks like there's some misunderstanding. The image i attached is the output image which i'm getting now from they code pasted above it.

Comment: @SaadAzhar - I think I was just being dense yesterday. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current calculation gets you an integer number of **hours** and a fractional representation of **seconds**; however, when working with Oracle dates, numbers added to dates represent an integer number of **days** and a fractional representation of **time within the day**. The conversion is simple enough - divide your value by 24, or in this case simply eliminate the multiplication by 24. That gives you a fractional day value. Now, to format this as `HH:MI` you need to convert it to a valid date, and the simplest thing to do here (since you don't actually care about the year/month/day values) is to just add your computed value to `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`. Doing this converts your value to an Oracle DATE, and from there you can use TO_CHAR to get the `HH:MI` as a formatted string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) +
                 (TRUNC(lt.DATE_START + 1) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND - lt.DATE_START), 'HH24:MI') DUR,
       lt.DATE_START
  FROM LOSTTIME lt
  WHERE lt.DATE_START >= TO_DATE('02/07/2020 08:00' , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f8fa493cb410652b26e144f94a3c025)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a function, it makes the final query simpler. Function accepts *number of days* as a parameter and returns it *formatted*.

```
SQL> create or replace
  2     function f_days2ddhhmiss (par_broj_dana  in number)
  3        return varchar2
  4     is
  5        l_broj_dana  number := par_broj_dana;
  6        retval       varchar2 (20);
  7     begin
  8        with podaci
  9             as (select trunc (l_broj_dana) broj_dana,
 10                        round (mod (l_broj_dana * 24, 24), 2) broj_sati,
 11                        round (mod (l_broj_dana * 24 * 60, 60), 2) broj_minuta,
 12                        round (mod (l_broj_dana * 24 * 60 * 60, 60), 2)
 13                           broj_sekundi
 14                   from dual)
 15        select    lpad (trunc (p.broj_sati), 2, '0')
 16               || ':'
 17               || lpad (trunc (p.broj_minuta), 2, '0')
 18          into retval
 19          from podaci p;
 20
 21        return retval;
 22     end f_days2ddhhmiss;
 23  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Now, your query (see comments within the code).

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data; you already have that
  3  losttime (date_start) as
  4    (select to_date('07/02/2020 08:16', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:Mi') from dual union all
  5     select to_date('07/13/2020 08:24', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual),
  6  -- this is your current query; I just removed *24 as function expects number of DAYS, not HOURS
  7  yourquery as
  8    (select ((trunc(lt.date_start + 1) - 1/(24*60*60)) - lt.date_start) dur, lt.date_start
  9     from losttime lt
 10    )
 11  select dur, date_start, f_days2ddhhmiss(dur) result
 12  from yourquery;

       DUR DATE_START RESULT
---------- ---------- ----------
,655543981 02.07.2020 15:43
,649988426 13.07.2020 15:35

SQL>
```

As the function *calculates* number of days and seconds as well, you can include them into the output, if you want. I didn't feel like removing them from the function. Or, you can even move that code *out* of the function and put it to query itself, but it gets somewhat messy (and probably faster).

Comment: Who else can answer this apart from Littlefoot.

Comment: Almost everyone here, @Ankit :), but thank you for being so kind :)

Comment: @Littlefoot unfortunately i have access only to read the records, no creation of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to calculate the ELAPSED_TIME in format HH:MI, I use this query

```
SQL> select * from my_test ;

C1                  C2
------------------- -------------------
2020-07-26 01:03:51 2020-07-26 19:03:51
2020-07-26 10:08:45 2020-07-26 14:38:45
2020-07-26 11:39:10 2020-07-26 13:54:10


SQL> select c1,c2,
TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(c2-c1, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
   || ':' ||
 TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(c2-c1, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
  as elapsed_time  from my_test ;   2    3    4    5

C1                  C2                  ELAPSED
------------------- ------------------- -------
2020-07-26 01:03:51 2020-07-26 19:03:51 18:00
2020-07-26 10:08:45 2020-07-26 14:38:45 04:30
2020-07-26 11:39:10 2020-07-26 13:54:10 02:15

SQL>
```

If you want the elapsed time with seconds

```
SQL> select c1,c2,
  2  TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(c2-c1, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
   || ':' ||
 TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(c2-c1, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
  3    4    5     || ':' ||
  6   TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(c2-c1, 'DAY')), 'FM00') as elapsed_time
 from my_test ;  7

C1                  C2                  ELAPSED_TIM
------------------- ------------------- -----------
2020-07-26 01:03:51 2020-07-26 19:03:51 18:00:00
2020-07-26 10:08:45 2020-07-26 14:38:45 04:30:00
2020-07-26 11:39:10 2020-07-26 13:54:10 02:15:00

SQL>
```

Be aware that this query will only work as long as the difference between the end time and the start time is lower than 24 hours.